# I have a problem with the 'UPDATE' command in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

i have a question about the "UPDATE" in my sql;
I have these datas:

```
create database execicios
default character set utf8
default collate utf8_general_ci;


create table if not exists contas_a_receber(
 Nome char(40),
 Numero int not null,
 Valor decimal(10,2),
 Vencimento date,
 Banco char(10),
 primary key (Numero)
)default charset = utf8;


insert into contas_a_receber values
('ABC PAPELARIA', '100100', '5000.00', '2017-01-20', 'ITAU'),
('LIVRARIA FERNANDES', 100110, 2500.00, '2017-01-22', 'ITAU'),
('LIVRARIA FERNANDES', '100120', '1500.00', '2016-10-15', 'BRADESCO'),
('ABC PAPELARIA', '100130', '8000.00', '2016-10-15', 'SANTANDER'),
('LER E SABER', '200120', '10500.00', '2018-04-26', 'BANCO DO BRASIL'),
('LIVROS E CIA', '200125', '2000.00', '2018-04-26', 'BANCO DO BRASIL'),
('LER E SABER', '200130', '11000.00', '2018-09-26', 'ITAU'),
('PAPELARIA SILVA', '250350', '1500.00', '2018-01-26', 'BRADESCO'),
('LIVROS MM', '250360', '500.00', '2018-12-18', 'SANTANDER'),
('LIVROS MM', '250370', '3400.00', '2018-04-26', 'SANTANDER'),
('PAPELARIA SILVA', '250380', '3500.00', '2018-04-26', 'BANCO DO BRASIL'),
('LIVROS E CIA', '453360',  '1500.00', '2018-06-15', 'ITAU'),
('LIVROS MM', '453365', '5400.00', '2018-06-15', 'BRADESCO'),
('PAPELARIA SILVA', '453370', '2350.00', '2017-12-27', 'ITAU'),
('LIVROS E CIA', '453380', '1550.00', '2017-12-27', 'BANCO DO BRASIL'),
('ABC PAPELARIA', '980130', '4000.00', '2016-12-11', 'ITAU'),
('LIVRARIA FERNANDES', '770710', '2500.00', '2016-11-15', 'SANTANDER'),
('ABC PAPELARIA', '985001', '3000.00', '2016-09-11', 'ITAU'),
('PAPEL E AFINS', '985002', '2500.00', '2016-03-12', 'SANTANDER'),
('LER E SABER', '888132', '2500.00', '2017-03-05', 'ITAU');
```

I wanna change all the words wrote 'SANTANDER' for 'BANCO DO BRASIL'
I was try use the command UPDATE, but is not worked

The command that i used is:

```
set Banco = 'BANCO DO BRASIL'
where Banco like 'SANTANDER';
```

Somone can help me?

Comment: Your syntax for update command is so wrong.

Comment: Your Banco column is a `char(10)`, and `BANCO DO BRASIL` is larger than 10 characters...

Comment: Cannot reproduce. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8823377d2d6fe3500e98203499ead2a7) (`Banco` definition adjusted).

Answer (score 1):

Use `UPDATE contas_a_receber set Banco = 'BANCO DO BRASIL' where Banco like 'SANTANDER%';`

The column Banco datatype is char(10) not varchar(10), which means the database will fill with blank until have 10 chars, like "SANTANDER ".

One more thing, BANCO DO BRASIL has more than 10 char, so it will crop or fail.
You need to change it to allow more than 10 chars:

```
ALTER TABLE contas_a_receber MODIFY Banco varchar(50)
```

But make sure it will have no implications in your system.